# How can I set header in "onException" to make it visible till the end of camel route?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to set some "flag" (I thought of header) which would say that an exception has occured and then at the end of route use it to log some info in 2 cases:
- when the were no exceptions
- when there was an exception

I tried setting the header in "onException" but it wasn't visible at the end of route.

```
onException(SomeException.class)
                .process(someExceptionProcessor)
                .handled(true)
                .end();

from(someSource)
  .split(body())
     .inOnly(someQueue)
  .end()
  .choice()
     .when(header("CamelSplitComplete").isEqualTo("true")) // here I would like to add something like "and(header("exceptionOccurred").isEqualTo("true"))"
         .log("Completed without issues")
     .otherwise()
         .log("Some issue occurred")
   .end();
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't visible because in the `onException` part you have `handled(true)`. That means that if the current Exception is raised, then route breaks and execution happens in the onException part, and doen't return back to the initial route. That is the reason why you couldn't see the log messages.

Try `continue(true)`. With this option if the Exception is raised flow will go to onException part. At there you can create your flag (`setHeader`) and then flow goes back to the route, so you will see the log messages that you want.

Comment: I tried putting ````continued(true)```` instead of ````handled(true)```` but still it does not work. Header which I set in ````onException```` is not visible further in route.

Comment: @abrams trying to resolve same issue(setting header after onException block), do you recall what was the solution there?